# NOT NULL constraint failed: users_userprofile.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to insert `django form` data inside the `UserProfile` model in my app. I tried using the `django shell` and `views.py` but I keep getting this error.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    qrcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    present = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
@staticmethod
def generate_qr(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MakeAttendance(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            course = form.cleaned_data.get('courses')
            section = form.cleaned_data.get('section')
            year = form.cleaned_data.get('year')
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            userobj = UserProfile(qrcode=unique_id)
            userobj.save().filter(course=course, section=section, year=year)
    return redirect('/users/dashboard')
```

This question has been answered many times here, but none of the solutions worked for me. I tried Creating a user profile with `get_or_create` method. I tried deleting my entire database and making migrations again. I manually tried to pass the user ID but nothing.

Comment: what is the traceback?

Comment: here's the full traceback http://dpaste.com/1HK99VZ. You might be interested in knowing the following messages  `The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: users_userprofile.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception: `  `Error in formatting: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: UserProfile has no user.`

Comment: UserProfile requires a user instance, first create a user then do the `UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=UserObjectCreated)`

Comment: Hey @SammyJ Thank you for the reply. I am creating a user instance and I still get this error. I have a variable named `profile` with the same exact code you posted. I misread that, let me try it and see if it works. EDIT - I tried it using `UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First create a user using `user=User.objects.create_user(username=request.user, password='password')`, then save it using `user.save()` and create profile using `profile=UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`. The reason this error occours is because the UserProfile looks for a user instance which you did not provide.

Comment: Hey @SammyJ I tried your solution, it outputs the following `'User' object is not iterable` on the line `user = User.objects.get_or_create(request.user)`

Comment: @Sahil I don't think it is my code that you have tried

Comment: Hey @SammyJ I created a new question which is simpler for me to define as well as for others to understand. If you'd take a look at it I'd be thankful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687968/how-to-insert-data-into-a-relational-one-to-one-table-in-django

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these two line

```
userobj = UserProfile(qrcode=unique_id)
userobj.save().filter(course=course, section=section, year=year)
```

In the first line you created an instance of `UserProfile` with only `qr_code`
and in the next line you are trying to save it which will try to insert a new row in the database without the user.

Comment: Hey @MohitSolanki, I understand the problem is in those lines but I don't understand how to solve them. This is how I saw how to insert data in models. Can you suggest a solutions please.

Answer (score 0):

in models.py you should create user object:

```
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

before class creating