# How to insert data into a relational one to one table in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `UserProfile` table which is in relation with the default Django `User` table. Here's how it looks.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = user.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    qrcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    present = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am trying to insert the data into the UserProfile table using the `Django Shell`.

```
from users.models import UserProfile

a = UserProfile(qrcode="hello")
a.save()
```

This is how I have always known to insert data into tables, it has always worked. BUT when i try to do this in `UserProfile` model. I get this exception. **NOT NULL constraint failed: users_userprofile.user_id**. Which in turn is caused by the following exception **Error in formatting: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: UserProfile has no user**.

I somewhat understand that I somehow need to *supply* a *user instance*. But I am clueless as to how. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to create User.

```
u1 = User(username='user1')

u1.save()
```

Create a UserProfile. Pass the ID of the “parent” object as this object’s ID:

```
v1 = UserProfile(user=u1, ....)
v1.save()
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your User first

```
user = User.objects.create(username='user')
```

and then you can do:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, ...)
```